# Show that the dihedral group $D_6$ of order $12$ has a nonidentity element $z$ such that $zg = gz$ for all $g ε D_6$.

Tags: dihedral-groups

From notes, I think all of the following are true:

- Every element of $D_6$ can be written as $s^ir^j$, where $i = 0,1$ and $0\le j\le 5$.
- $r^6 = e$, where $e$ is the identity.
- $s^2 = e$
- $r^ks = sr^{-k}$ for any integer $k$.

Do I actually have to find $z$? If not, how would I prove its existence? I'm guessing I would have to suppose I have some $z$ such that $zg = gz$ and then have to show it is an element of $D_6$?

Comment: What's wrong with actually finding such a $z$? You have the multiplication rules.

Comment: All you have to do is to find a $z$ commuting both with $s$ and with $r$.

Comment: Hint: $r^3=r^{-3}$

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: FYI, you can use \in for $\in$